# Heroku rails deployment issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to push my rails app to deployment via Heroku and whenever i do, i'm getting thrown this error:

```
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.0
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       /usr/bin/env: ‘jruby’: No such file or directory
       Bundler Output: /usr/bin/env: ‘jruby’: No such file or directory
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Jruby seems to be playing into this somewhere but i just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure your application to run with default mri ruby or with jruby? If you are using jruby did you follow all step in the Heroku documentation to enable jruby support?

Comment: App is using default ruby set to 2.7.0. The only instance where jruby is mentioned at all is  within the gem file: ```gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', platform: :jruby```

Answer (score 0):

Answer has been solved as of today. The problem was that somewhere along the line, jruby got included in the list of gem dependencies and snowballed into everything else. In order to fix the problem, I needed to remove all instances of jruby from all folders within the app and it was able to compile properly and deploy.